# Required property 'probability' not found in JSON. Path

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am deserializing to the following class:

```
public abstract class Tail_Metrics
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
    public double probability { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
    public double min { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public double max { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 4, IsRequired = true)]
    public double mean { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public double variance { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public double skewness { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 7)]
    public double kurtosis { get; set; }
}
public class Layer_Tail_Metrics : Tail_Metrics { }
```

As you can see, probability, min, and mean are required, the rest are optional.

I am deserializing the following JSON response from my server:

```
{
    "probability": 0.01,
    "mean": 0,
    "variance": 0,
    "min": 0,
    "max": 0
}
```

And I am getting a `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException` with the message `Required property 'probability' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 95.`

How can that be? The property is present in the JSON, and has the correct type!

The weirdest thing is that if I remove the `IsRequired` property from the `DataMember` attributes, I stop getting this exception and the object deserializes perfectly. If any of them has the `IsRequired` property set to true, that property throws the same exception.

---

Deserialization code is:

```
T retVal = converter.Deserialize<T>(response);
```

where `typeof(T)` is `Layer_Tail_Metrics`

`converter` is a class implementing `RestSharp.Deserializers.IDeserializer` as follows:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public class RestSharp...Converter :  RestSharp.Deserializers.IDeserializer
{
    //...
    private JsonSerializerSettings deserializerSettings;

    public RestSharpDataContractNewtonsoftJsonConverter()
    {
        Culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        ContentType = "application/json";

        deserializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            Converters = new JsonConverter[]{
                new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter()
            }
        };
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response)
    {
        return Deserialize<T>(response.Content);
    }
    public T Deserialize<T>(String json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, deserializerSettings);
    }
}
```

---

Here is a small standalone sample that reproduces the error:

```
[DataContract()]
public abstract class Tail_Metrics
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public double probability { get; set; }

    public Tail_Metrics(double probability)
    {
        this.probability = probability;
    }
}
public class Layer_Tail_Metrics : Tail_Metrics
{
    public Layer_Tail_Metrics(double probability) : base(probability) { }
}

class TestClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""probability"": 0.01
        }";
        Layer_Tail_Metrics tm = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Layer_Tail_Metrics>(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the part where you do the deserialization?

Comment: Can you post your deserialization code?  Also -- what happens when you remove the 'IsRequired' attribute from just probability? (Is it a problem with all the required fields -- or just probability?)

Comment: Try changing the Order attribute of probability to 0 and hence all subsequent Order values to 1 less than they are. Could be a problem with it starting at 1 instead of 0? (I doubt it, but it's worth a quick try since I can't think what else could be causing this).

Comment: @Stijn I've added the deserializer.

Comment: @DanEsparza This only happens when I have the `IsRequired` attribute set. If I remove it from `probability`, it moves on to complaining about `min`. If I remove it from all of them, the class deserializes fine and all the values come through!

Comment: @DeeMac - the order appears to have no impact (it's only used for serializing).

Comment: I tried to simplify things for my question, but I've added in one layer of complexity because I think it might be relevant - the class I'm deserializing to inherits all those properties from an abstract base class. These inherited properties are the only ones causing problems. Properties with `IsRequired` set don't cause problems in the derived class!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine for me using the following console program with JSON.Net v5.0.8 (the latest in NuGet):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""probability"": 0.01,
            ""mean"": 0,
            ""variance"": 0,
            ""min"": 0,
            ""max"": 0
        }";

        var tm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Layer_Tail_Metrics>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("probability: " + tm.probability);
        Console.WriteLine("mean: " + tm.mean);
        Console.WriteLine("variance: " + tm.variance);
        Console.WriteLine("min: " + tm.min);
        Console.WriteLine("max: " + tm.max);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Layer_Tail_Metrics : Tail_Metrics 
    { 
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Tail_Metrics
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
        public double probability { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
        public double min { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public double max { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 4, IsRequired = true)]
        public double mean { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 5)]
        public double variance { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 6)]
        public double skewness { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 7)]
        public double kurtosis { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
probability: 0.01
mean: 0
variance: 0
min: 0
max: 0
```

Is the JSON you posted the full JSON response you get from the server, or is it wrapped in an outer object?  If it is wrapped in another object, then that could explain the problem.  For example, if your JSON actually looks like this:

```
{
    "response":
    {
        "probability": 0.01,
        "mean": 0,
        "variance": 0,
        "min": 0,
        "max": 0
    }
}
```

and you try to deserialize it into `Tail_Metrics`, then JSON.Net will not be able to match any of the properties, because they are all one level further down in the JSON.  If you have set "IsRequired = true" on the properties then this will cause JSON.Net to throw the exception you are seeing.  If you remove it, then JSON.Net will simply assign a default value of zero to the `double` properties in your class for which it can't find a match in the JSON.  If all your data happens to be zero in the JSON anyway, then it will look like it's working even if it really is silently failing.

Comment: Hi Brian - Thanks for trying to reproduce this problem. The response isn't wrapped in anything. To be certain - if I remove the `IsRequired` property from the `DataMember` attributes, the whole object deserializes without complaints. I've updated my question with a little more details about what I'm doing. The properties in question are actually inherited from an abstract base class in my exact situation. Do you think that could be a cause?

Comment: It's possible.  Let me update the test code to consider this and give it a try.

Comment: It still works for me.  Do both your abstract and concrete classes have the `[DataContract]` attribute on them?  Also, what version of JSON.Net are you running?

Comment: You're right, your test class is working, so it's not the abstract base class. It fails for my class but not this simplified one. I'm going to have to start adding in the Constructors, methods, etc until I find out what is causing the error.

Comment: Alright, I found a very tiny set of test code that can reproduce the error. I've added it to the end of my question. Please see if you get the error as well. It seems to be related to the presence of a constructor.

Comment: Problem goes away when I add an empty constructor :/ Guess I need one of those for when the converter creates a new instance of my class to deserialize to. It was a very misleading error.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to ask you whether your class had an empty constructor.  Usually if you don't have one, JSON.Net will complain with a different error about not being able to create an instance of the object.  Strange that it is not doing that in this case.